# Custom HTML structure for woocommerce Product variation

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I want to get a custom Layout for a Single Product page.

[here](https://orebrostudio.com/product/delineator-table-01/) is my page

For **now**, I can see the Structure like this

```html
<div class="qodef-woo-single-summary">
 <div class="summary entry-summary">
 <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
```

But I want to change my structure Like this

```html
<div class="qodef-woo-single-summary">
 <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
 <div class="summary entry-summary">
```

How can I change structure?
I can access to FTP server Please Help me!
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a child theme if it does not exist already, and copy the appropriate template file from your parent theme to your child theme and edit from there. For the single product page this is most likely single-product.php